# How to find the substring if the substring has random characters replaced?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, substring

Let's say we have a string in Python:

```
original_string = "TwasTheNightBeforeChristmasWhenAllThroughTheHouse"
```

And we are interested in finding the beginning coordinates of the substring `substring ="ChristmasWhen"`. This is very straightforward in Python, i.e.

```
>>> substring ="ChristmasWhen"
>>> original_string.find(substring)
18
```

and this checks out

```
>>> "TwasTheNightBeforeChristmasWhenAllThroughTheHouse"[18]
'C'
```

If we tried to look for a string which didn't exist, `find()` will return -1.

Here is my problem:

I have a substring which is guaranteed to be from the original string. However, characters in this substring have been randomly replaced with another character.

How could I algorithmically find the beginning coordinate of the substring (or at least, check if it's possible) if the substring has random characters `'-'` replacing certain letters?

Here's a concrete example:

```
original_string = "TwasTheNightBeforeChristmasWhenAllThroughTheHouse"
substring = '-hri-t-asW-en'
```

Naturally, if I try `original_string.find('-hri-t-asW-en')`, but it would be possible to find `hri` begins at 19, and therefore with the prefix `-`, the substring `original_string.find('-hri-t-asW-en')` must be 18.

Comment: Yes this is what regexp are for. Search for ".hri.t.asW.en" with rexexp module.

Comment: When you get the substring, do you know which one is the weird character? Also, is it the same one for the whole substring, or could it be, for instance `-` and `_` as intruders in the same substring?

Comment: @PedroAlves I know what the weird character is. It's only `-`

Comment: Then @Jean-BaptisteYunès's suggestion is the way to go: convert your input to the correct regex pattern (basically just replace `-` by `.`) and use that pattern to search the string (see the `re` module for documentation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is typically what regular expressions are for : find patterns. You can then try:

```
import re                       # use regexp
original_string = "TwasTheNightBeforeChristmasWhenAllThroughTheHouse"
r = re.compile(".hri.t.asW.en") # constructs the search machinery
res = r.search(original_string) # search
print (res.group(0))            # get results
```

result will be:

```
ChristmasWhen
```

Now if your input (the search string) must use '-' as a wildcard you can then translate it to obtain the right regular expression:

```
import re 
original_string = "TwasTheNightBeforeChristmasWhenAllThroughTheHouse"
s = ".hri.t.asW.en"              # supposedly inputed by user
s = s.replace('-','.')           # translate to regexp syntax
r = re.compile(s)
res = r.search(original_string)
print (res.group(0))
```

Comment: Of course, you would need to replace the `-` with `.`. It takes no more than `substring = substring.replace("-", ".")`

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I hadn't realized this functionality existed in such an user-friendly form

Answer (score 2):

perhaps use a regular expression? For instance, you can use the `.` (dot character) to match any character (other than a newline, by default). So if you modify your substring to use dots instead of dashes for the erased letters in the string, you can use `re.search` to locate those patterns:

```
text = 'TwasTheNightBeforeChristmasWhenAllThroughTheHouse';
re.search('.hri.t.asW.en', text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expresions to find both the match and the possition

```py
import re
p = re.compile(".hri.t.asW.en")
for m in p.finditer('TwasTheNightBeforeChristmasWhenAllThroughTheHouse'):
    print(m.start(), m.group())

out: (18 ChristmasWhen)
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex approach, less efficient than the latter, but still a possibility:

```
o = "TwasTheNightBeforeChristmasWhenAllThroughTheHouse"
s = '-hri-t-asW-en'
r = next(i for i in range(len(o)-len(s)) if all(a == b or b == '-' for a, b in zip(o[i:i+len(s)], s)))
```

Output

```
18
```